# Web authentication issue using Script Task in SSIS

Tags: c#, vb.net, web, ssis, ssis-2012

Hi I am using Script Task to download a file from a website but I seem to be having problems. I can't get past the web page which asks for Username and password. In the Connection Manager Editor I have listed the URL address and User Name and Passwords and the Test Connection Succeeded. So I am not sure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

```
namespace ST_054ab1f1837a4b9d8f167cfd91109f9b
{
/// <summary>
/// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
/// or parent of this class.
/// </summary>
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // Logging start of download
            bool fireAgain = true;
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Start downloading " + Dts.Connections["HTTP"].ConnectionString, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

            // Get your newly added HTTP Connection Manager
            Object mySSISConnection = Dts.Connections["HTTP"].AcquireConnection(null);

            // Create a new connection
            HttpClientConnection myConnection = new HttpClientConnection(mySSISConnection);

            // Download file and use the Flat File Connectionstring (D:\SourceFiles\Products.csv)
            // to save the file (and replace the existing file)
            myConnection.DownloadFile(Dts.Connections["FileName"].ConnectionString, true);

            // Logging end of download
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Finished downloading " + Dts.Connections["FileName"].ConnectionString, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

            // Quit Script Task succesful
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Logging why download failed
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Download File", "Download failed: " + ex.Message, string.Empty, 0);

            // Quit Script Task unsuccesful
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As it is, your code doesn't set the ServerName/ServerPassword. Did you forget to set them or did you remove them before posting?

Comment: I added the User Name and Password within the HTTP Connection Manager Editor. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message it just bring the page where you need to provide User Name and Password but I was expecting to go past that page because I have already provided the User Name and Password on the HTTP Connection Manager. I hope I made sense to you?

Comment: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/greenmtnsun/archive/2007/09/06/http-authenticatoin-download-of-file-in-ssis-to-csv-file.aspx  ......hope this helps

Comment: i'm having same issue, Please share us solution if you're able to get it.